# How to select a column name and use it as input for a variable name in Python?

Tags: python

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I'm writing a while loop to loop over certain columns. In this while loop I want to create a variable of which the name partly consists of the column name it is looping over.

```
x=2
length=len(grouped_class.columns)
while x<length:
    x=x+1
    (grouped_class.columns[x])_largest = x+5
    ...
```

This is my current code (=x+5 is not actual code, but as example), but it returns a syntax error. If I run grouped_class.columns[x] in the shell it returns the name of that column, for example : "ColumnA". I want to use this "ColumnA" as first part of a variable name.

So in the variable list it would return: `ColumnA_largest`

In this way I can store the result for each column in a seperate variable.

How can I do this?

**EDIT: QUESTION GENERALIZED**

How can I use a string obtained by `df.column[x]` as input for a variable name?

Example df:

```
ColumnA    ColumnB    ColumnC
5          6          4
6          10         2
```

If I run `df.columns[1]` it returns `"ColumnB"`

I want to use this `"ColumnB"` as part of the name when assigning a variable.

Imagine I want to create the variable `COLNAME_sum = x + 5`
I would like to change the COLNAME to the string I obtained from `df.columns[1]` (="ColumnB")

Expected output:
A variable named `ColumnB_sum`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you show example of input and expected output? If you need help look at how to provide [mcve].

Comment: It is a complicated dataset and I did not eleborate on that because it would possible be distracting. I also think it is not relevant for the question (perhaps I'm wrong). I would just like to know how to use a string value as part of a variable name.I can edit the question to make it more general.

Comment: I edited the question, is it more clear now?

Comment: @Robvh my answer below explains how it can be done explicitly, but should be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't create variables *on-the-fly* as it could lead to many issues, instead, use dictionary:

```
largest = {}
x = 2
length = len(grouped_class.columns)
while x < length:
    x = x + 1
    column = grouped_class.columns[x]
    largest[column + '_largest'] = x + 5
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, this basiscally does what I want, but I'm stumbeling upon a new problem. In my real code I've now written: ```largest={}
x=2
length=len(grouped_class.columns)-1
while x<length:
    x=x+1
    largest[grouped_class.columns[x]+"_largest"]=grouped_class.nlargest(5,[grouped_class.columns[x]])```. So for each grouped class column I want the rows with  5 largest values. However, it now makes a dictionary with the correct keys ```COLNAME_largest``` but the values are wrong. It returns 5 values for every column and not just the selected one. Only the values of the selected one are sorted.

Comment: for each key (= column name) I want only like the sorted values of that column name.

Comment: @Robvh I've added part with `column` variable so you can use `grouped_class[column].nlargest(5)` or even add `.tolist()` at the end of it.

Answer (score 1):

**Right way:**
The right (Pythonic) way is to use dictionaries.

```
columns = {}
columns[some_string] = some_value
```

**Unadvised dirty way, but answers your question:** Storing a *string* as a *variable name* in your global namespace can be done simply by (example):

```
some_value = 100
some_string = 'var_name'
globals()[some_string] = some_value
```

The output is then

```
>>> var_name
100
```

On the other hand, if you want to add a variablename locally, you can use `locals()` instead of `globals()`.

I trust you can take over from here!

Comment: I edited my answer to make it more compliant to general expectations.

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to do that. Of course dirty tricks can allow it, but the *Pythonic* way is to use a dictionary:

```
largest = {}
x = 2
length = len(grouped_class.columns)
while x < length:
    x = x + 1
    largest[grouped_class.columns[x]] = x + 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using a pandas dataFrame. You can use:

```
dict = {}
my_dict[grouped_class.columns[x]+'_largest'] = x+5
```